# MySQL insert statement won't work without hard coding the id (primary key)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

The MySqlCommand is resulting in an error "id can't be null"

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand($"insert into dataBase.testingTable (id, value1, value2, value3) values (null,'test','2021-1-1', 9)", connection);
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteReader();
connection.Close();
```

The below statements also yielded Id related errors:

```
insert into dataBase.testingTable (value1, value2, value3) values ('test','2021-1-1', 9) //id column is missing

insert into dataBase.testingTable values ('test','2021-1-1', 9) //column number mismatch
```

How do I solve this error.

I am using MySQL server, MySQL workbench and Visual Studio's WPF Framework.

The table in Workbench
[image]

Comment: Can you post your table definition? You must have set ID column as NOT NULL.

Comment: The structure of the table would be useful

Comment: If `id` is auto incrementing, you should just leave it out of the `insert`. If it isn't, you should supply a value

Comment: of course it is since the id is the primary key and it can't be null

Comment: "of course it is" *what*? It's obviously NOT an AI. It should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your First Query is failing because **ID Column is PRIMARY KEY column which cannot be assigned NULL.**

Second one is failing because, **ID column is NOT NULL and you have not listed it in INSERT statement.**

Third one is failing because **you have not mentioned column names in insert statement due to which system is expecting values of all 4 columns but you are providing only 3.**

**Solution for all the above problems is : Make your ID column AUTO INCREMENT or Provide a NON-NULL Unique value for each row inserted.**